# Exporting SHP files into AutoCAD readable files?

Tags: qgis, export, autocad, dxf

I have a full water supply network drawn in a shapefile which I created using Qgis 2.2.0.
Now I need to export it into a format that enables me to open it in AutoCAD.
I am trying to export it as a dxf file, but when I upload it in AutoCAD it shows an empty drawing (although the dxf file is 1.75MB).
The shapefile is a line shapefile with several lines with a different main attribute (the diameter).

Maybe I have to save different dxf for each diameter?

Comment: What version of AutoCAD are you using, and what flavor (by which I mean Civil 3D, Map, plain AutoCAD, AutoCAD Lite, etc.)? There are a number of questions and answers here regarding QGIS and dxf files. You may want to put "qgis dxf" in the search box at the top and browse through the results.